# Tellg returning unexpected value

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream, file-handling

I have a function which reads lines from a file. But before reading it returns the address from where its going to read the next line.

my function is:

```
void print()
    {
        int j=0;
        string a,b,c,d,e;
        ifstream i("data.txt");
        cout<<setw(15)<<left<<"Hash Value"<<setw(15)<<left<<"Employee Name"<<setw(15)<<left<<"Employee ID"<<setw(15)<<left<<"Salary"<<setw(15)<<left<<"Link"<<endl;
        while(j<10)
        {
            j++;
            cout<<i.tellg()<<endl;
            i>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;
            cout<<setw(15)<<left<<a<<setw(15)<<left<<b<<setw(15)<<left<<c<<setw(15)<<left<<d<<setw(15)<<left<<e<<endl;
        }
        i.close();
    }
```

The file it is reading from is data.txt:

```
      0            ---              0              0             -1
      1            ---              0              0             -1
      2            ---              0              0             -1
      3            ---              0              0             -1
      4            ---              0              0             -1
      5            ---              0              0             -1
      6            ---              0              0             -1
      7            ---              0              0             -1
      8            ---              0              0             -1
      9            ---              0              0             -1
```

And the output I am getting is:

```
Hash Value     Employee Name  Employee ID    Salary         Link           
0
0              ---            0              0              -1             
81
1              ---            0              0              -1             
157
2              ---            0              0              -1             
233
3              ---            0              0              -1             
309
4              ---            0              0              -1             
385
5              ---            0              0              -1             
461
6              ---            0              0              -1             
541
7              ---            0              0              -1             
617
8              ---            0              0              -1             
693
9              ---            0              0              -1
```

Every line is of length 76 characters. So everytime the address printed should increase by 76.
But i dont understand whats going on when the 2nd line is printed[hash value 1], and the 7th line is printed [hash value 6].

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Can you upload the text file here: http://textuploader.com/ , there might be special characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things:

- First and foremost, you're not reading line by line, so there
  is no reason to assume that you advance the number of characters
  in a line each time through the loop.  If you want to read line
  by line, use `std::getline`, and then extract the fields from
  the line, either using `std::istringstream` or some other
  method.
- The result of `tellg` is not an integer, and when converted to
  an integral type (not necessarily possible), there is no
  guaranteed relationship with the number of bytes you have
  extracted.  On Unix machines, the results will correspond, and
  under Windows *if* (and only if) the file has been opened in
  binary mode.  On other systems, there may be no visible
  relationship what so ever.  The only valid portable use of the
  results of `tellg` is to pass it to a `seekg` later; anything
  else depends on the implementation.
- How do you know that each line contains exactly 76 characters?
  Depending on how the file was produced, there might be a BOM at
  the start (which would count as three characters if the file in
  encoded in UTF8 and you are in "C" locale).  And what about
  trailing whitespace.  Again, if your input is line oriented, you
  should be reading lines, and then parsing them.
- Finally, but perhaps the most important: you're using the
  results of `>>` without verifying that the operator worked.  In
  your case, the output suggests that it did, but you can never be
  sure without verifying.

Globally, your loop should look like:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( i, line ) ) {
    std::istringstream l( line );
    std::string a;
    std::string b;
    std::string c;
    std::string d;
    std::string e;
    l >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> std::ws;
    if ( !l || l.get() != EOF ) {
        //  Format error in line...
    } else {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

Outputting `tellg` still won't tell you anything, but at least
you'll read the input correctly.  (Outputting the length of
`line` might be useful in some cases.)

Comment: I'll try this and ask you if i have any more issues! Thanks!